# Mat-Table from angular materials not displaying data

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I am trying to display some data from an api in a mat table. However, even though I can see the data in the console, it will not show up in the mat table. The console shows no errors concerning the mat table and the titles of the columns appear properly.

I have already tried to use the async keyword to get the rest api data before the rest of the component is loaded.

This is my component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'admin-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
  providers: [HTTPService],
  styleUrls: ['./admin.component.css']
})
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit{
  showForm= false;
  buttonName= "Add User";
  users:User= [];
  tableColumns: string[] = ['name', 'email', 'company', 'phoneNumber', 'enabled', 'status'];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private http: HTTPService){};

  ngOnInit(){
      this.getUsers();
  }

  async getUsers()
  {
    var arr= await this.http.listUsers().toPromise();
    var i=0;
    while(arr[i])
    {
      this.users.push(arr[i]);
      i++;
    }
    console.log(this.users);
```

This is the html template

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="users">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.name}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container  matColumnDef="email">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Email</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.email}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container  matColumnDef="company">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Company</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.company}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container  matColumnDef="phoneNumber">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Phone Number</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.phoneNumber}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container  matColumnDef="enabled">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Enabled</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.enabled}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container  matColumnDef="status">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user">{{user.status | lowercase}}</td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="tableColumns"></tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: tableColumns"></tr>
</table>
```

Please let me know if more information is required, I am new to StackOverflow

Comment: can you please create `stackblitz`.

Comment: What is the result of `console.log(this.users)`?

Comment: @IshanPhadke I think all is good problem is on data. you are not able provide data for table because if you provide static data its working fine you can check your data or  HTTPService what you can get. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-arzyzy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html here s your code working fine with static data.

Comment: @ElasticCode it prints out the user data from my api correctly

Comment: @Abhishek thank you for taking the time to make the stackblitz. I'm not sure whats going wrong with my HTTP service, I am receiving the proper user data in the correct format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `dataSource` of `mat-table` using `new MatTableDataSource` as follows.

**TS**

```
export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

    dataSource;

    constructor(...){};

    ngOnInit() {

        this.getUsers();
    }

    async getUsers() {

        const arr = await this.http.listUsers().toPromise();
        let i = 0;
        while(arr[i]) {
            this.users.push(arr[i]);
            i++;
        }
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>(this.users);
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource">
...
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it. Could you tell me why this makes a difference? I thought that the [dataSource] input function like the *ngFor directive.